# Unity3D: Convert all game objects to same size irrespective of it's scale

Tags: unity, c#, camera, scale

Suppose I have a reference GameObject, Cube, with scale (1,1,1). There is another GameObject with scale (1,1,1), but the size is 3 times bigger than the Cube. How do I dynamically change the scale of the Game objects to fit the size of the Cube?

Comment: Is something like renderer.bounds.size good enough for you?

Comment: yeah, that's good! so should I keep reducing the scale such that `renderer.bounds.size` is equal to the cube?

Comment: You should be able to calculate how much bigger/ smaller the second object is. Get the volumen from the reference object and the new object, divide them by each other and multiply your scale by the result. Should scale your second GO to a matching size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested, and completely from memory, but something kind of along these lines should work. I'll test it tonight when I have access to Unity.

```
//scales all GameObjects in goResizeList to have the same size as the referenceGO.
public void resizeAll(List<GameObject> goResizeList, GameObject referenceGO){
  Vector3 refSize = referenceGo.renderer.bounds.size;

  foreach(GameObject go in goResizeList){
     float resizeX = refSize.x / go.renderer.bounds.size.x;
     float resizeY = refSize.y / go.renderer.bounds.size.y;
     float resizeZ = refSize.z / go.renderer.bounds.size.z;
 
     resizeX *= go.transform.localScale.x;
     resizeY *= go.transform.localScale.y;
     resizeZ *= go.transform.localScale.z;

     go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(resizeX, resizeY, resizeZ);
  }

}
```